# how to get the explanation of the error in websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am new to websockets and I try to hanlde the errors they throw.

I have something like

```
websock.onerror=function (evt) 
 { alert(the reason it falied is...);}
```

How can I get the explanation of the error?

For example the console says "you cannot delete that because of restrictions in db".

How can I get this and display it to the user instead of just alerting "Error deleting"?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://cjihrig.com/blog/how-to-use-websockets/).

The parameter to your error handler is the error, so you can use that (`evt` in your example). Try `evt.message`.

Comment: I also tried something like `se.onclose = function(event) {  alert(event.reason)  ;` and alerts an empty box...